# Laravel whereDate() is not working as expected

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The following is part of my query for querying data between two dates:

```
->whereDate('fixture_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays($pastDays))
->whereDate('fixture_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->addDays($futureDays))
->when(request('search'), function ($query) {
    $query->orWhere('fixture_hometeam_name', 'LIKE', '%' . request('search') . '%')
          ->orWhere('fixture_awayteam_name', 'LIKE', '%' . request('search') . '%');
        })
```

When `request('search')` is empty, I am getting the expected results but when not, the `whereDate` queries are not working.

How should this be modified to give the correct results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another layer to add parenthesis around the `orWhere` of the search.

```
->whereDate('fixture_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays($pastDays))
->whereDate('fixture_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->addDays($futureDays))
->when(request('search'), function ($query) {
    $query->where(function($subQuery) {
        $subQuery->orWhere('fixture_hometeam_name', 'LIKE', '%' . request('search') . '%')
          ->orWhere('fixture_awayteam_name', 'LIKE', '%' . request('search') . '%');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereBetween` instead of two `whereDate`.

```
->whereBetween('fixture_date', [
    now()->subDays($pastDays)->startOfDay(), now()->addDays($futureDays)->endOfDay()
])->when($request->search, function ($query, $search) {
    return $query->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('fixture_hometeam_name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
              ->orWhere('fixture_awayteam_name', 'like', "%{$search}%");
    });
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping

> You should always group `orWhere` calls in order to avoid unexpected behavior when global scopes are applied.